# WordPress Rewrite url to get value in page

Tags: php, wordpress, plugins, url-rewriting

How can I get a value on the page? For example,

my page is:

`domain.com/mypage/`

my value is 'myvalue' in this page Similar below:

`domain.com/mypage/myvalue`

I want to get the amount of 'myvalue' on 'mypage' page, Please give me a complete code sample

Thank you for your answer

Comment: https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/250837/understanding-add-rewrite-rule

Answer (score 0):

i use this cod :

```
function foo_rewrite_rule() {
    add_rewrite_rule(
        'currency-analysis/([a-z0-9-]+)[/]?$',
        'index.php?page_id=563&currency-analysis=$matches[1]',
        'top');
}
add_action( 'init', 'foo_rewrite_rule' );
```